# Jenkins pipeline script error WorkflowScript: Expected a step

Tags: jenkins, syntax-error, runtime-error, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a testcase from a much bigger Jenkins pipeline project and it works fine.

```
pipeline { 
            agent none
        stages {     
            stage ("Check Parameters")
                          { 
                             steps {
                                     echo "In pipeline"
                                     script {
                                           echo "Start condition check"
                                                }
                                     build job: 'printuser'
                                     //def slaveJob = build job: 'printuser'
                                     //println slaveJob.rawBuild.log  
                                        }
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Howevr, inorder to get the output of printuser job onto the pipeline i comment build job: 'printuser' and uncomment the slaveJob code as below:

```
                                 //build job: 'printuser'
                                 def slaveJob = build job: 'printuser'
                                 println slaveJob.rawBuild.log
```

It now fails with the below error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 13: Expected a step @ line 13, column 15.
                                            def slaveJob = build job: 'printuser'
                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can you please suggest what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use groovy, you must put it **inside** the `script` section, not outside:

```
script {
    echo "Start condition check"
    build job: 'printuser'
    def slaveJob = build job: 'printuser'
    println slaveJob.rawBuild.log  
}
```

PS: not sure your code will work as such, but you should at least put it **inside** the `script` part. Outside of the `script` closure, `jenkins` will only accept a set of predefined **steps**.

Comment: So is it the println causing the issue?  Or 'def slave Job =' is the issue ?Because the job is getting triggered from outside the script.

Comment: the `groovy` syntax is causing trouble: both the `def` and the `println` probably

Comment: How do i print slaveJob.rawBuild.log for failing jobs ?

Comment: you can start by looking here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34726